# Second monitor needs restarting after system reboot

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, kde

I have a strange problem with my second monitor in KDE.

After setting everything up the system is very stable and I have no problems. However, when I restart the computer, my second display doesn't show any Desktop, Widgets, Panels, or Wallpaper. The mouse and applications can be dragged over no problem though so the monitor is indeed on and the system is still able to communicate with it.

In order to restore everything to a working state, I open DISPLAY CONFIGURATION and disable then re-enable the second monitor then all my desktop settings go back to normal. I could probably solve this in the short term by writing a start up script to do this for me every time I launch the system but I'm hoping somebody knows more about what is going on? I'm quite new to KDE so I'm not really even sure where to start looking for logs etc to see what is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

System spec is [here](http://pastebin.com/kvyFVFzH)

Comment: Hi, Magic, I am afraid a startup command (run it after a break of 10-15 seconds after log in) is the best solution. Most likely, communication between graphics driver and screen catches a cold during login, and this is what happens. The command to set up the screen will then fix it. Possibly switching driver, if possible, will fix it alternatively.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Do you happen to know the best way to tap into the KDE desktop via command line? DSUB seems like it's the way to go?

Comment: Do you mean the command to set up the screen correctly?

Comment: I'm looking in QDBusViewer and found the org.freedesktop.DisplayManager service, I think I'm close but don't know how to dig further into what is available. Obviously the functionality is there, hence the display manager having the buttons to press, but how can I determine what their command line equivalent is? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I have the same problem. Now I have to restart my second screen several times, after a boot, or after coming back from lock. Did you find a way to manage it ?

Comment: @Jean-Marc I used to have this problem a long time ago, but I no longer have this problem on 23.10. Have you tried upgrading to a newer Kubuntu version?